# I can't install paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, imagemagick, paperclip

I'm new in rails, I need to install Peperclip (https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) and i can't, I have looked every tutorial I can find and I haven't been able to find where is the bug. I installed the ImageMagick and follow all the instruction of github.
When I run:

```
rails generate paperclip club imagen
```

I got this

```
/Users/Moski/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/generators/actions/create_migration.rb:13:in `migration_file_name': protected method `migration_file_name' called for #<PaperclipGenerator:0x000001053fbb68> (NoMethodError)
    from /Users/Moski/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/generators/actions/create_migration.rb:34:in `existing_migration'
    from /Users/Moski/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/actions/empty_directory.rb:112:in `invoke_with_conflict_check'
    from /Users/Moski/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/actions/create_file.rb:60:in `invoke!'
    from /Users/Moski/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/actions.rb:94:in `action'
    from /Users/Moski/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/generators/migration.rb:36:in `create_migration'
    from /Users/Moski/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/generators/migration.rb:65:in `migration_template'
    from /Users/Moski/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/paperclip-4.1.1/lib/generators/paperclip/paperclip_generator.rb:16:in `generate_migration'
    from /Users/Moski/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    from /Users/Moski/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
    from /Users/Moski/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `block in invoke_all'
    from /Users/Moski/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `each'
    from /Users/Moski/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `map'
    from /Users/Moski/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `invoke_all'
    from /Users/Moski/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/group.rb:232:in `dispatch'
    from /Users/Moski/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/base.rb:440:in `start'
    from /Users/Moski/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/generators.rb:156:in `invoke'
    from /Users/Moski/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/commands/generate.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/Moski/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
    from /Users/Moski/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `block in require'
    from /Users/Moski/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/Moski/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
    from /Users/Moski/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:48:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Someone can help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It looks like an existing issue in `paperclip`. You would need to source `paperclip` directly from GitHub.

Refer to this open issue in [Paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/issues/1495)

You can source `paperclip` from Github by adding the following line in your Gemfile:

```
gem 'paperclip', github: 'thoughtbot/paperclip'
```

-OR-

```
gem 'paperclip', :git => "git://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip.git"
```

Comment: According the open issue article all you have to do is put `gem 'paperclip', github: 'thoughtbot/paperclip` command in your Gemfile. Then run the `bundle install. Also, says ruby 2.1.1 and rails 4.0.4 combination was the issue. Just making it easy for those who don;t have time to read long articles.

Comment: @user3317140 +1 Thanks! I added it in the answer. You had a missing end quote :)