# paperclip Ruby on Rails 4 install Error?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip

after adding gem and bundle install, I tried to generate paperclip but I get error?

In GemFile

```
      gem "paperclip", "~> 4.1"
```

In command line:

```
 $   rails generate paperclip user avatar
```

Error I get:

```
   /Users/amirna/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/generators/actions/create_migration.rb:13:in `migration_file_name': protected method `migration_file_name' called for #<PaperclipGenerator:0x007fc6c7e43690> (NoMethodError)
from /Users/amirna/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/generators/actions/create_migration.rb:34:in `existing_migration'
from /Users/amirna/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/actions/empty_directory.rb:112:in `invoke_with_conflict_check'
from /Users/amirna/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/actions/create_file.rb:60:in `invoke!'
```

Comment: It is an existing issue with paperclip. You will have to source the paperclip gem from `Github` instead of `rubygems`.

Comment: Read the linked answer, the one I marked in the first comment http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22739370/i-cant-install-paperclip

Comment: You can always(almost always) install directly from github using:
    gem 'gemname', github: 'gemOwner/gemname'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a documented issue at `PaperClip` - https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/issues/1495

Change that to :

`gem 'paperclip', github: 'thoughtbot/paperclip'`

Answer (score 2):

You should try the migration manually if the generator doesn't work. Or if the above answer doesn't fix it.

```
class AddAvatarColumnsToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_attachment :users, :avatar
  end

  def self.down
    remove_attachment :users, :avatar
  end
end
```